# Secured WMS call from web application

Tags: geoserver, wms, security

I have a GIS application where users have to login in with username and password. The WMS is served using GeoServer and displayed using OpenLayers. I need to restrict WMS layers.  I want to access the secured layers via WMS without exposing my credential. Is there any method for this? Just like URL filtering.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.